# Partial vs. Exact Matching in Sphinx

Tags: php, sphinx

I'm trying to set up a simple query (taken from a user search), to find results within what is currently a simple table of Book Titles and Authors.  I'm just using this as a test to get to grips with Sphinx a little.

My PHP so far is this:

```
$oSphinx->setFieldWeights(array('title' => 50, 'author' => 10));
$oSphinx->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$oSphinx->setSortMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE);
$oSphinx->setRankingMode(SPH_RANK_SPH04);
$rMatches = $oSphinx->query('Sarah J. Maas');
```

My maximum infix and word length are 3, so I am assuming the "J." gets stripped out of the query for search purposes.  My problem is that these 2 results are returned:

Sarah J. Maaster

Sarah J. Maas

They both have the same weighting, and they appear in that order in the data set, so that's the order Sphinx returns them.  Is there a way to weight the "exact" match above the more fuzzy one?  I know there's an exact_hit modifier but that doesn't seem to have any effect here (it's contained within SPH_RANK_SPH04 anyway).  My expectation would be that the second one would have a higher weighting because "Maas" matches a full word in that result and not a substring, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

I am using Sphinx 2.0.4 (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Package).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any morphology that might be turning `Maaster` into `Maas`?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on `expand_keywords` 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/manual-2.0.4.html#conf-expand-keywords

and `index_exact_words`
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/manual-2.0.4.html#conf-index-exact-words

Will need `enable_star` too :)
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/manual-2.0.4.html#conf-enable-star